# Can I use below like this?

Tags: prepositions

Let's say my friend and I are going through a stack of books, 
He says

> This book looks interesting, I am going to buy it.

I want to ask if the book **below** that one looks good as well, Can I say

> What about the book **below**?

Is **below** as an adverb correct here?

Comment: I'd probably say, "What about the book _under_ that one?" (or maybe _underneath_).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, first off it isn't an adverb. I'm not sure if you tagged the question yourself or if somebody did it for you, but it is indeed a preposition.

Otherwise, your example sentence is not incorrect, but it's also not the most natural phrasing. Most speakers would be more likely to say "*What about the book **under** that one?*" The prepositions "under"/"underneath," and "below" are fairly similar in their dictionary meanings, but are generally used in different ways.

**Under** is used when something is directly underneath another object, especially if it's being covered or hidden. A man would conceal a weapon *under* his coat, during a storm you may hide *under* a table, or perhaps you could drop your keys and lose them *under* the seat.

**Below**, on the other hand, simply indicates relative position and is more likely to be used when the two things in question are not immediately next to each other. Submarines cruise around *below* the surface of the water, my friend lives in an apartment a few floors *below* mine, and the molten core of our planet is far *below* the surface.

Although those are examples in which **below** is preferred, you can usually use **under** instead without sounding at all unnatural. The reverse is not always true. So, when in doubt, stick with *under*. Learning to use below in a sentence which sounds natural to native speakers is a skill that will come with time.

---

**A brief note:** *Below* is also used when imagining a sort of.. non-physical "vertical scale" rather than talking about actual positions. I could say a family lives *below* the poverty line, that the temperatures tonight may drop *below* freezing, or that a person is of *below* average intelligence. In this context it would be very bizarre to use *under* instead.

Comment: The OP's question hasn't been edited, so you can tell he tagged it himself.  (If there's no text like *"edited 2 hours ago"*, it means that the question hasn't been edited.  If there is, you can click that text to show an edit history.)

Comment: Yeah that is me!! may be one of my alternate personalities :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would say OP's example looks more *adjectival* than *adverbial*, since the only thing it seems to modify is the noun *book*. Informally, it's a perfectly common usage, but note what OED has to say...

> (defn 4): Directly beneath; under the covering or canopy of; underneath.
>    *More strictly expressed by **under, beneath.*** (italics mine).